# How can I make my cards independent from each other?

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create an interactive dashboard on Power BI and there is something that is driving me crazy.

Here's the situation, I have on my dashboard two slicers, one to choose the year and one to choose the business unit I want to see data from. I also have two cards, one to display the net income per year and one to display the net cash flow.

When I choose a year and a business unit, I want to see the net income related to that year and business unit but also the net cashflow.

However, it seems that my two cards are linked. Here's an illustration to make things more easy to understand:

[image]

The values of my cards are always identical. If I change one it changes the other. Why?

How can I make them 'independent'?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use (Format --> Edit Interactions)

Comment: Are you using different measures for the cards?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you need to adjust interactions between slicers and cards.
Click on slicer > Format and click on Edit interactions
[top menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J6JR.png)

You will see Filter and None icons on each of the card visuals and second slicer.
Check None on the card which should not be affected by visual.
[card visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEdUC.png)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. However it doesn't solve my problem.
I want both my cards to be affected by the slicers, but I just want them to show different data.
When I want to see data for the year 2020, I want one of the card to show me the Net Income in 2020 et the other one to show the Cash Flow in 2020. :/